# How to add new Build Configuration(Ex: Debug_UAT, Release_UAT) for only one Target in Xcode 15?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode15, xcode-target

I added new **Build Configurations** to my Project by going to the

> Project->Info

tab in **Xcode 15**. But it is getting applied to all the Targets of the project.

I want to add the new **Build Configurations** only to specific **Target**. Is that possible on **Xcode 15**? I researched a lot but couldn't find an answer.